# Let T(n) be defined by the following recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, solution-verification

Let T(n) be defined by the following recurrence relation

$\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
T(0) = T(1) = 1 \\
T(n) = T(n−1) + T(n−2) + 1 \quad for \quad n ≥ 2
\end{cases}
\end{equation}$

Show that T(n) = $2F_n − 1$  for $n \geq 0$,
where
$F_n$
is the
$n$'th Fibonacci number, i.e.

$\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
F_0 = F_1 = 1 \\
F_n = F_{n−1} + F_{n − 2} \quad for \quad n ≥ 2
\end{cases}
\end{equation}$

I'm attempting to do this by induction, but perhaps it might not be the best route, I'm not entirely sure. I get stuck using that method. Any insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the first equalities,

$$2T(0)-1=2T(1)-1=1$$
and from the recurrence

$$2T(n)-1=2(T(n-1)+T(n-2)+1)-1=2T(n-1)+2T(n-2)-1,$$

and you recognize the definition of the Fibonacci numbers.